# Расстояние между словами в Android?

Tags: android, строки

Как можно в строке изменить расстояние между словами в Android , в коде, с помощью метода?

Comment: Разбить строку по пробелам и склеить обратно, добавив неразрывных пробелов?

Comment: Спасибо, работает, а есть какая то возможность регулировать размер пробела?

Comment: Теоретически, можно пробелы обернуть в спан, в котором настроить размер. Попробуйте как-то так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47694060/3212712